# Postgresql full text search for similar words

Tags: postgresql, dictionary, full-text-search

Trying to implement postgresql full text search example by following these steps;

I have created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE posts
(
id serial primary key,
content varchar(255),
tags varchar(255),
title varchar(255)
);
```

Altered the table to have a column of type TSVECTOR

```
ALTER TABLE posts ADD COLUMN searchtext TSVECTOR;
```

Created a trigger to store data in searchtext column:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ts_searchtext BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON posts FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger('searchtext', 'english', 'title', 'content', 'tags')
```

I have inserted a row:

```
insert into posts(content,tags,title) values('once upon a time I had a fat friend','friend, fat','Fat Boy');
```

Value under searchtext column is:

```
"'boy':2 'fat':1,10,13 'friend':11,12 'time':6 'upon':4"
```

Now, when I run query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts where searchtext @@ to_tsquery('english','fot');
```

It returns 0 rows.

So, basically I am looking for a solution where "fot" should have been matched against "fat" or we can say looking for result based on matched letters out of word.

or if we run:

```
SELECT * FROM posts where searchtext @@ to_tsquery('english','frend');
```

It should match against "friend". As per documentation of postgresql I think it will be done with the help of dictionaries. But now sure which .dict and .affix file should I use. Can anyone help me with more understanding on this.

Comment: how many cases do you have such as `fot = fat , friend = frend` ? I'm not sure about `Thesaurus Dictionary` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch.html) as well as I don't know how Postgres can understand `fot = fat, friend = frend` by itself. I think you can define a `table` which contain `words` you want to map.

Comment: We need to put such entries in .syn file, but when I try to use it, its not working.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use pg_trgrm https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtrgm.html

Your query will turn into:

SELECT * FROM posts where (content || tags || title)  <% 'frend'

But this will not use fulltext capabilities. It still can be indexed via GIN, though

Answer (score 0):

Try with plainto_tsquery function:

`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE searchtext @@ plainto_tsquery('english frend');`